# lpr command is different on the dev and production machine?

Tags: cups, lpr

I'm printing some files (labels) directly from the server. On my development machine (Xubuntu 12.04) the following works:
lpr -P QL-720 -H 192.168.171.53 /tmp/labels/OAQRJECIDP

On the production server (Ubuntu 12.04 server) it does not. I get a response on how to use it:
usage: lpr [-cdfghlmnpqrstv] [-#num] [-1234 font] [-C class] [-i [numcols]]
    [-J job] [-Pprinter] [-T title] [-U user] [-wnum] [name ...]

Obviously these lpr commands are not the same one??

When entering man lpr on dev machine it says Apple Inc. lpr - print files
on the server man lpr BSD General Commands Manual lpr - off line print

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the lpr is available through several different packages. I had to remove lpr from the server and then install cups-bsd which contains lpr command I needed.